# Convert HH:MM:S to seconds int

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, datetime-conversion

I have two columns with the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
When I do the difference between these two columns, my result has a format of the form HH:MM:SS

I would like to convert this result into seconds. How can I make it?

Example:

```
2019-06-15 19:27:33.045000 | 2019-06-15 19:27:22.298000 | 00:00:10.747
```

Comment: In Postgres you could do `to_char(timestamp '2019-06-15 20:27:33.045000' - timestamp '2019-06-15 19:17:22.298000', 'hh24:mi:ss')` - does this work in Redshift as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF ( datepart, {date|timestamp}, {date|timestamp} )` function for more info [check here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html)

for e.g

```
 select datediff(second, '0','05:15:40');
```

Comment: Check Datediff is avilable in redshift?  If yes then try like this SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,'20:10:10')

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
Declare @time varchar(50)= '05:15:40'
select Sum(Left(@time,2) * 3600 + substring(@time, 4,2) * 60 + substring(@time, 7,2)) 
as seconds
```

OR

```
Declare @time varchar(50)= '05:15:40'
SELECT seconds = DATEPART(SECOND, @time) +  60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, @time) + 
3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, @time)
```